# Can't run a function. Overload takes 0 arguments

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a script which has the void called TakeDamage. For debugging purpose, whenever I press 'k' TakeDamage is called. Here's my script, it says

```
No overload for method 'TakeDamage' takes 0 arguments
```

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tfXBdzxS9K/

Answer (score 1):

You call the method when `k` is pressed like this:

```c#
if (Input.GetKeyDown("k"))
{
   TakeDamage();     
}
```

But your method definition expects an `int` as parameter as in

```c#
public void TakeDamage (int amount)
```

You need to call the method with an `int` as damage amount like this:

```c#
if (Input.GetKeyDown("k"))
{
   TakeDamage(10);     
}
```